# Unable to put output of basic calculator in a variable, formatting bytes to MB in bash

Tags: bash, arithmetic

I want to get my data usage from my wifi device to display on my top bar, I can get the data usage in bytes using curl like this

`$bytes=(curl -d "Page=GetWANInfo" -X POST  http://jiofi.local.html/cgi-bin/qcmap_web_cgi -s| jq -r .total_data_used)`

it gives me a big number like `411982397` now I want to convert it in MBs and want to display it like `411.9 MB`

but I am unable to figure out how can I format that big number like this.

I tried using `bc` to convert it into MB `echo $bytes / 1000000 | bc`

but I am unable to put that into a variable it is giving me errors.

```
$ total=($bytes / 1000000 | bc)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
$ total=$($bytes / 1000000 | bc)
411982397: command not found
$ echo "$bytes / 1000000" | bc
411
$ total=$("$bytes / 1000000" | bc)
bash: 411982397 / 1000000: No such file or directory
```

my Idea here is to put that output in a variable than I can just `echo $total MB`

What can be a better approach for this problem? also I need to run this command every few seconds so I need a efficient solution to the problem which is easy to cpu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jq` can do the division:

```
$ echo '{"total_data_used":411982397}' | jq -r '.total_data_used/1e6|tostring + "MB"'
411.982397MB
```

Most modern shells (zsh, ksh93, yash, fish at least) can do it as well by themselves if you don't have to use bash specifically.

In zsh:

```
printf -v total %gMB $(( bytes / 1_000_000. ))
```

(note the `.` to force floating point arithmetic. You could also use `1e6`).

ksh93's `printf` also has builtin support  to convert to human readable formats with kMGTPE suffixes, both using 1000 based and 1024 units:

```
$ printf '%#dB\n' bytes
412MB
$ printf '%#iB\n' bytes
393MiB
```

In bash specifically, for the special case of dividing by a power of 10, you can use its `printf` though by appending `e-6` to the integer and use it as an argument for `%e`, `%f`, `%g`, `%a` (or uppercase variants).

```
printf -v total %gMB "${bytes}e-6"
```

The default precision for `%g` is 6 significant digits, you can change that if you like with `%.12g` for instance for 12 digits. Note that `printf` (in both bash and zsh at least) honours the locale's decimal radix character. For instance, you'll get 411.982MB in an English locale and 411,982MB in a French/German... locale.

To get `bc` to do the division, you'll need to feed the expression on its stdin, either by piping the output of a command that outputs it, typically, `printf` is used for that¹, or by using a here-document (standard `sh`) or here-string (from zsh, but found in many other shells these days), and then get its output through a pipe using command substitution for instance to store into the `total` variable.

But you'll want to set its `scale` special variable which tells it how many digits after the radix to compute upon division (0 by default, unless the `-l` option is used in which case it's 20 instead). So:

```
total=$(
  printf 'scale=2\n%d / 1000000\n' "$bytes" | bc
)
```

Or:

```
total=$(
  bc << EOF
scale=2
$bytes / 1000000
EOF
)
```

An alternative to `bc` is `awk` which can do floating point arithmetic and format numbers with its own `printf`:

```
total=$(
  jq... | awk '{printf "%gMB", $0 / 1e6}'
)
```

---

<sup>¹ `echo` is also commonly used but [as it's got a non-portable and unreliable API, it's best avoided in the general case to output arbitrary data](/q/65803)</sup>

Comment: that's a tons of info, I am very new to bash scripting so It was very helpful thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for `total=$(echo "$bytes / 1000000 " | bc)`.

Comment: thanks, it was helpful